# How to get xemacs-like Buffers menu entry in emacs?

Tags: buffers, mouse, ibuffer

xemacs has a nicely organized Buffers entry in its built-in menu. As you can see from the snapshot, it's sorted alphabetically and grouped by modes:

[image: xemacs buffers menu]

I can't find how to make emacs do the same. `menu-bar.el` provides a very rudimentary recent 10 entries listing. I looked at `menu-bar-update-buffers` and I don't see how I could adjust things on the user-side, short of rewriting that function. Unfortunately I don't know lisp.

Do you know of anybody implementing an alternative version?

I'm aware of C-left-mouse-click `mouse-buffer-menu` - which is much better (does grouping and sorting), but requires more steps to get to the right buffer when grouped. And when forced to not group (via large setting for `mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult`), it throws them all into one pile.

I'm aware of ibuffer and its extensions (and set it to `C-x C-b`), which is even better and more customizable - but I can't see how I could inject its listing into the menu bar. Other than going through Buffers -> *IBuffer*. Is there way to replace that entry, so that the Buffers menu entry will take me directly to *IBuffer* listing?

Comment: Have a look at the variables:  `buffers-menu-max-size`; `buffers-menu-buffer-name-length`; `buffers-menu-show-directories`; `buffers-menu-show-status`; `list-buffers-directory`; ...  To read the doc-string, type `C-h v` or `M-x describe-variable`.

Comment: For the mouse version, have a look at the variables:  `mouse-buffer-menu-maxlen`; `mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult`; `mouse-buffer-menu-mode-groups` ...

Comment: Thank you, @lawlist. As I mentioned in the OP I have already tried  `mouse-buffer-menu-*` options. None give me I get with xemacs's Buffers.

Comment: I have never used Xemacs, but as long as the code that interests you is written in Lisp, there is probably no reason we cannot just make it work with a current version of Emacs.  Do you have a version number of Xemacs and/or a link to the source code that you have fallen in love with so that we can take a peak and see if the buffer menu listings is easily portable?

Comment: Ha, any version would do - it hasn't changed since 2000. I looked through the code - it appears to be `sort-buffers-menu-by-mode-then-alphabetically` in [lisp/menubar-items.el](http://www.mit.edu/afs.new/athena/contrib/xemacs/arch/sun4x_55/lib/xemacs-21.4.4/lisp/menubar-items.el). But then it's tied to a very different internal structure. My feeling is that it'd be a huge project, but perhaps you'd see it in a different way. Thank you for looking at it, @lawlist

Comment: Here is a first draft of an attempt to port the Xemacs buffer menu-bar functionality:  https://gist.github.com/lawlist/651685e64bc4d471def7c87e0ef46a65 .  I have not yet spent any time making `complex-buffers-menu-p` compatible; and, I am still unfamiliar with all of the possible settings.

Comment: Please kindly add instructions on using it. Adding `(require 'buffer-menu.el)` at the end of the init file fails with `failed to provide feature ‘buffer-menu.el’`. Thank you.

Comment: Let us assume that Emacs has created a folder called `.emacs.d` inside your HOME directory and we will refer to it as "~/.emacs.d".  Now, let us suppose that we want to create a directory for beta testing Lisp libraries -- to that end, we will create the folder `beta-testing` inside the `~/.emacs.d` directory, and the path to that new directory that we just crated will be `~/.emacs.d/beta-testing`.  Now, let us visit the Gist on the internet and we see a button "Download ZIP" and we go for it and download the zipped archive to a place such as our Desktop or other location of your choice. ...

Comment: ... We then extract the file `buffer-menu.el` to the new directory we just created in the previous comment; i.e., `~/.emacs.d/beta-testing`.  The path to the file will now be `~/.emacs.d/beta-testing/buffer-menu.el`.  Now we must add the new directory to our `load-path` by adding the following line to our `.emacs` / `init.el` file:  `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/beta-testing/")`.  Somewhere after the line where we just added the folder `beta-testing` to our `load-path`, we can then put `(require 'buffer-menu)`.  There is no need to use a `.el` at the end.  We are only **beta testing**!

Comment: I appreciated all the details, it was already all setup up, but for some reason I Ieft `.el` in the require call - removing it made it work. Looks fantastic! Now if it's not too complicated it just needs to sort alphabetically within each group and move the \*xxx\* buffer group to the end, have \*List all buffers\* at the top and it'll be a perfect match. Wow!

Comment: I'd be happy to work on it in my spare time and hopefully within a reasonable period of time all of the features will be working properly.

Comment: I believe everything is now working.  I submitted a link of the gist (above) to https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/ in the hopes of enticing some beta testers.  It is about 550 lines of code, which may or may not exceed the permissible character limit for an answer on emacs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Fabulous! It's feels more like home now ;) Thank you, @lawlist! There is one typo: "List All Buffer" should be plural "List All Buffers". So once you're happy with it, can you submit it into some sort of public repository so others could find it in case your gist disappears one day?

Comment: Thanks for beta testing.  The typo has now been fixed.  I am working with Github tech support to fix an issue with file creation on its repositories and will place the library there for public consumption once the technical issue is resolved.

Comment: Excellent! I noticed another small issue, please see: https://i.imgur.com/JDr4pEz.png those leading % misalign the listing, making the text column start unbalanced.

Comment: The default setting of Xemacs assigned `%` to everything, probably for speed.  The slower non-default setting used `%` to indicate `read-only`, which is how the default Emacs does it.  I fixed the Xemacs deault setting to really query whether the buffer is `read-only` and if so, then use `%`.  I think we should keep the `%` as it is useful, which would mean that the non-read-only without `%` need padding on the left to push them over so that the alignment is the same as those with `%`.  We would need to query `buffers-menu-max-size` to see if padding is 0-9 or 0-99 -- one or two paddings.

Comment: or, now that I think about it some more, probably just a padding of one (1) on the left is sufficient for `non-read-only` buffers because Xemacs buffer menu switches to lowercase letters after `0` (aka ten).  Does that sound like what you had in mind to fix the alignment issue?

Comment: It doesn't really matter to me what route you think is the best, as long as all the buffer text entries are vertically left-aligned. I never got % in my xemacs setup.

Comment: A plain old space did not work for me as padding because the font used by the Emacs menu-bar on my machine/OSX is proportional.  The unicode Figure Space -- 'Tabular width', the width of digits (aka U2007) seems to work for this particular situation; i.e, it is same width as a `%` in my setup.  The next draft is ready (it incorporates `?\u2007` instead if `non-read-only`).

Comment: it's still not quite aligned on my system (linux) (I can add a snapshot, but it's probably unnecessary, it's just not aligned). Perhaps moving all the status symbols to the end of the line would be a simpler solution? Otherwise, even if the padding works for you and me, it might still not work on a different setup.

Comment: The menu-bar does not offer a flush-right feature, so we'd have the same alignment issue. I added two new variables named `buffers-menu-read-only-string` and `buffers-menu-read-write-string`, which have default settings of `%` and unicode symbol `U2007` respectively.  These can be customized, for example as follows:  `(setq buffers-menu-read-only-string "")` and `(setq buffers-menu-read-write-string "")` for nothing preceding the underscore symbol.  Or, any combination of characters to form a string.  `(setq buffers-menu-read-only-string "☺☺")` and `(setq buffers-menu-read-write-string "☻☻")`.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting to align thing to the right, just moving the readonly/write status symbol to the end of the entry (after the buffer name). But your new variables work perfectly well for me as I don't care for that status. In fact your modification is great as now I get less noise. Everything else looks great. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**REPOSITORY**:  https://github.com/lawlist/buffer-menu

**CLONE REPO**:  git clone https://github.com/lawlist/buffer-menu.git

The porting of the Xemacs buffer-menu features to Emacs 26 resulted in the creation of a library consisting of 600+ lines of code.  Approximately 99.9 percent of the code is straight from Xemacs, with a few modifications by @lawlist where particular Lisp functions did not exist or they are somewhat different in Emacs 26.  The general format for creating a menu in Emacs 26 is a little different than in Xemacs.  Installation instructions are contained in the repository.  Here are some screenshots:

https://www.lawlist.com/images/buffer_menu_a.png

https://www.lawlist.com/images/buffer_menu_b.png

https://www.lawlist.com/images/buffer_menu_c.png

https://www.lawlist.com/images/buffer_menu_d.png

Comment: Thank you very much for taking so much of your time to port this xemacs feature to emacs, @lawlist! It feels great to have this feature in emacs now!